# how to trigger a java script confirm box after the page loads completely

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to reload a PHP script on my page when I submit a form. When I submit, it has to load on the same page. When the form is submitted, I need to show the confirmation window to the user. However, the problem is that the confirm box is shown while the page is loading (and the page doesn't finish loading until the user selects an option).

```
------------<? if(){?>

<script>
if(confirm){
}else{
}
</script>
```

I need the confirm box to be triggered after the page loads completely. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the window.onload event:

```
window.onload = function () {
   if (confirm...) {
      ...then...
   } else {
      ...else...
   }
}
```

or (what is better) use jquery:

```
$(function () {
   if (confirm...) {
      ...then...
   } else {
      ...else...
   }
});
```

Comment: Why is the latter the better?

Comment: It's not better. Only different. If you use the JQuery framework, go with it; if not, there's no need to use it.

Comment: Yeah, why is using jQuery better than using the DOM0 `onload` event?? ;)

Comment: 1. "window.onload = " overwrites onload - when some code assigned a value to it then this value will be lost.

Comment: 2. jquery actually assigns function no on onload, but on DOM ready event when it is available and contains a lot of code for cross-browser compatibility.